# null reference exception while passing event handler in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

i want to send message while typing text by using websocket.

but have websocket reference error while typing text.

i think ShareTextComponent onInputEvent function parameter is not exeucte in another location.

so websocket property can't reference in this field

but i don't know how can i fix it.

and i didn't use any state management library such as redux and mobx.

just pure reactjs

[error]

[image]

[code]

```
const ShareTextComponentView = (props) => {

const [isShareMode, setShareMode] = useState(false)
const [syncText, setSyncText] = useState("")
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false)
const [name, setName] = useState("")

let ws = null;
const connect = () => {
    ws = new WebSocket(ADDRESS + `/${name}`)

    //액세스코드들을 전부 보냄
    ws.onopen = () => {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({command: "CONNECT", accessCode: generateAccessCode()}))
        console.log(`${ADDRESS}에 접속 되었습니다.`)
        setOpen(true)
    }

    ws.onclose = () => {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({command: "CLOSE"}))
        console.log(`${ADDRESS}에 접속 종료 되었습니다.`)
        setOpen(false)
    }

    ws.onmessage = (evt) => {
        if (isShareMode) {
            return
        }

        const message = JSON.parse(evt.data)
        console.log({message: message})
        setSyncText(message.data)
    }
    ws.onerror = (err) => {
        console.log("접속중에 에러가 발생되었습니다.")
        console.log(err)
    }
}

const close = () => {
    if (ws !== null && ws.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED) {
        ws.close()
    }
}

// p2p로 웹소켓으로 연결
useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
        return
    }

    connect()
    setOpen(true)

    return () => {
        //만약 공유모드를 종료했을때 websocket에 shutdown 메세지를 보냄
        if (isOpen) {
            close()
            console.log(`${ADDRESS}에 접속 종료 되었습니다.`)
        }
        setOpen(false)
    }

}, [isShareMode])

const onTextInput = (text) => {
    const {name, value} = text.target

    if (!isShareMode) {
        return
    }

    console.log("websocket status")
    console.log(ws)
    console.log("input value")
    console.log(value)
    if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.CLOSED) {
        console.log("Connect Close 되었습니다.")
    } else {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({command: "SEND", message: value}))
    }
}

const generateAccessCode = () => {
    return "hello"
}


const reconnect = () => {
    connect()
    console.log(ws)
}
return (
    <div className="container">
        <h1> Please Enter This Area Section</h1>
        <h1> {isOpen ? "Connect" : "Disconnect"}</h1>
        <div className="name-container">
            <label> Name : </label>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => {
                setName(e.target.value)
            }}/>
        </div>
        <button className="reconnect-mode" onClick={reconnect}>Connect</button>
        <button className="is-receiever" onClick={() => setShareMode(!isShareMode)}>공유자 입니까?</button>
        <h1>{isShareMode ? "공유모드" : "수신모드"}</h1>
        <ShareTextComponent accessCode={generateAccessCode()} onInputEvent={onTextInput} syncText={syncText}/>
    </div>
)
}
export default ShareTextComponentView;
```

[after logging in onTextInput]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a null check to the top of the function ->

```
const onTextInput = (text) => {
    if (!ws) return;
```

This will at least help you get past that error and narrow down the rest of the flow.

Comment: but i want to send server while typing text. so i want to ws property is not null in onTextInput method.


however while reconnect function is work property while i've check the log 

but only onTextInput ws proptery is emtpy :(

Comment: i don't know why ws property have null after connect function is work property

Comment: Ah, I think it's because you are re-defining `ws` with every component render.  Either pull this out of the component or make the variable a ref with the `useRef` hook.  It will not change on re-render and once `connect` is called it will be set up for use in the other functions.